# Java JodaTime wrong seconds format

Tags: java, jodatime, date-formatting

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(2017, 2, 27, 17, 50, 31);
System.out.println(now.toString("s") + " <-- must 3\n" + now.toString("ss")+" <-- must 31");
```

output:

```
31 <-- must 3
31 <-- must 31
```

somtimes i get correct result mostly wrong!

JodaTime 2.9.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc for `DateTimeFormat`:

> Number: The minimum number of digits. Shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. When parsing, any number of digits are accepted

Thus `s` specifies that the output must be *at least* one digit. If the seconds were less than 10 it would be one digit, but with numbers ≥ 10 you will get two digits.

BTW, it makes absolutely no sense to truncate the numerical value `31` to only `3`.